# connecting css file to html on godaddy

Tags: html, css, web

So I have been trying to get my website up and working for the past couple days on godaddy. I was able to get it up without any trouble, however I cannot seem to get my css files to link properly. I feel like I am setting the path correctly as well which is weird. I have been using code igniter for this project and have my code igniter folder in the public_html folder.

So the path that I used to link my css file is `home/username/public_html/ci/css` (and yes my css folder is in the ci folder). Now, when I open up my website and do inspect element I get a bunch of 404 failed to load errors. However I know these files are there because when I go to sources and look for them in the inspect element I can see them there.

However, when I click on the files they are completely blank! I know these file are not blank though. I feel like something is blocking the files from loading but don't know what it is. Anyone have any ideas what might be wrong?

My site is [mathscienceandstuff.com](http://mathscienceandstuff.com/) if you want to inspect element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you specify is incorrect - you are giving the file path as found on the server, but this is not how the browser views it.

`public_html/` is, as you might guess, where a public browser 'sees' - so your HTML paths are relative to there.

Note that the address

```
mathscienceandstuff.com/ci/css/style.css
```

points to a file which exists, whereas

```
mathscienceandstuff.com/home/username/public_html/ci/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

does not.

Comment: Wow. You are the best! Thank you so much! Worked right away. Sorry for being soo dumb.

Comment: @user3630439 if the answer worked then thank him by accepting his answer by clicking the check mark next to his post.

Comment: @user3630439 No problem - we're all 'dumb' before we learn ;)